# Will this expression work?

Tags: perl

I am completely new to Perl and need some help understanding someone's code.
Pasted below is a snippet of Perl code. Can you help me understand what it means?

```
my @m1 =keys( %{$key} );
foreach (@m1){
    if (m/^(.*)\/$/) {   
             $a=$1;
} }
```

This does not seem to work. Will this actually match the values in m1 with the capture group? Will the variable a contain the match of the capture group?

And what does the keys function actually do?

Comment: If you don't know what `keys` actually does, how can you say that your snippet *does not seem to work*?

Comment: Sorry this question is maybe incorrect. i have posted a more detailed question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323423/reading-windows-regsitry-with-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unnecessarily noisy. This sort of code is why Perl gets trashed. It's the same as

```
my @m1 = keys %$key;

for (@m1) {
  if ( m|^(.*)/$| ) {
    $a = $1;
  }
}
```

It loops over all the keys in the hash referred to by `$key` (setting `$_` to each of them) and checks whether they end in a slash character `/`. If so, then `$a` is set to the key string without the terminating slash.

I assume there must be more to the loop than you have shown, because as it stands it is of little use.

Comment: You can go one further and loop through the keys directly.  `for (keys %$key)`